# Spring Sentry Integration. Event processor doesn't work (prevent health check)

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j, sentry

I need to prevent sending some events by condition. (health check)

I'm using spring libraries:

```
implementation "io.sentry:sentry-spring-boot-starter:5.4.1"
implementation "io.sentry:sentry-logback:5.4.1"
```

It works, sentry has a lot of transactions etc. The configuration is:

```
sentry:
  dsn: https://....ingest.sentry.io/....
  traces-sample-rate: 1.0
```

I'm going to prevent some events which has health check data using event processor:
https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/spring-boot/advanced-usage/#registering-custom-event-processor

```
@Component
public class SentryCallbackExtension implements EventProcessor {

    @Value("${app.sentry.exclude.transactions}")
    private List<String> excludes;

    @Override
    public @Nullable SentryEvent process(@NotNull SentryEvent event, @Nullable Object hint) {
        return StringUtils.containsAnyIgnoreCase(
            event.getTransaction(), excludes.toArray(new String[0])
        ) ? null : event;
    }
}
```

Configuration for this block is:

```
app:
  sentry:
    exclude:
      transactions: "/actuator/health"
```

And it doesn't work. There are a lot of health check events in sentry service.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used TracesSamplerCallback (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/spring-boot/configuration/filtering/#using-sampling-to-filter-transaction-events) and it helps. It can prevent all events/transactions (not only custom from application).

```
@Component
public class SentryTraceSamplerCallback implements TracesSamplerCallback {

    /**
     * Excludes transaction paths
     */
    @Value("${tn.sentry.exclude.transactions}")
    private List<String> excludes;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
    public @Nullable Double sample(@NotNull SamplingContext context) {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getCustomSamplingContext().get("request");
        String url = request.getRequestURI();
        return StringUtils.containsAnyIgnoreCase(url, this.excludes.toArray(String[]::new)) ? 0.0D : 1.0D;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`EventProcessor` interface has two methods:

- `SentryEvent process(SentryEvent event, Object hint)` - for processing events
- `SentryTransaction process(SentryTransaction transaction, Object hint)` - for processing transactions

Since you want to filter out transactions created from requests to the health endpoint, you need to implement the second method that takes `SentryTransaction` as the first parameter.

Comment: I was triyng, it didn't help... It prevents only custom applications transaction and events.